# Ubuntu server 19.04

Tags: networking, server, configuration

I have a problem with my Ubuntu server 19.04. I installed today but I can not even reach my home router. I would be like to be connected by DHCP to the router. Please tell me what should I do ? :)

I searched for a tricks and ideas on the Internet but they did not help me!! Maybe because of the new version 19.04 is the newest!!

[.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ383.png)
[resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foWIB.png)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: It works now. I found my small misstake 
Thank you for caring

Comment: What did you find?

Comment: the problem was that I do not give the interface the right and apt name with the Hardware
the name right name is ens33 and I wrote in the configurations ens3 LOL

now I have a new Question and maybe you can help:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156751/changed-commands-in-new-versions

Comment: In your .yaml file your wrote enp3s0?