# Changed Commands in new Versions

Tags: command-line, server, software-installation

How can I found out a changed Commandin for new Version....
As you now the command are diffrent from Version to another and if I want to install for example (Sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt mysql-server phpmyadmin -->it has worked on ubuntu server 18.02) on the new version ubuntu server 19.04 but I do not found the command because it has been changed

thanks for helping :)

Comment: Commands generally don't change, package version available does. I'm not sure about the package  php7.0-mcrypt since it doesn't exist in official repositories of Ubuntu 18.04. Do you use some 3rd party repository for that package?

Comment: The correct command would be `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt mysql-server phpmyadmin`... small s in sudo, but the php7.0-mcrypt package doesn't exist. Maybe you obtained it elsewhere. So you could do `sudo apt-get install mysql-server phpmyadmin`

Comment: No I dont do ! but a friend of me has used the command and it works

Comment: How/where did your friend obtain php7.0-mcrypt? Were they running Ubuntu, or something else? The latest php is version 7.2, and you wouldn't want to install an old 7.0 version anyway.

Comment: @heynnema oh thank you it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

re: `Sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt mysql-server phpmyadmin`

The correct command would be `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt mysql-server phpmyadmin`... small `s` in sudo, but the `php7.0-mcrypt` package doesn't exist in the Ubuntu repositories, so you can't install it. Maybe you obtained it elsewhere. And since the latest php is 7.2, you wouldn't want to install an old 7.0 version anyway.

So you could do `sudo apt-get install mysql-server phpmyadmin`

Comment: would you tell me how you found that out ?

Comment: I looked in `synaptic`.

Comment: mcrypt is deprecated in PHP 7.2 according to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1037418/20275

Comment: okay thank you for helping